# ie browser iframe has src source but body and head is empty

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, iframe

the problem is when use IE browser, find the iframe has src source but body and head is empty, while copy this src can open at new ie page, thanks for answer!

[image]

Comment: Could you please details about IE version and elaborate the problem.

Comment: The iframe might be blocked due to `CSP` headers. Either the current page doesn't allow iframes or the target iframe has `frame-ancestors` set.

Comment: IE version is 11

Comment: code just like this: <iframe  style={{ width:100%, height:100%, border: 'none}}
allow='*' src={`${window.location.origin}/mladmin-sub/pages/#${key}`}

Comment: Does your Iframe show any error on the web page? If yes, try to inform us may help to narrow down the issue. Further, try to use the HTTPS protocol for both the parent page and I frame page. see whether it helps to fix the issue. If the issue persists then try to add this code `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/> ` in the head part of the parent page. See whether it makes any difference.

Comment: there is no error in Console, but just an warring ‘Dom7011: the code on this page has reverse and forward caching disabled. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337’，and both the parent page i used HTTP,and i just add code <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;IE=EDGE;chrome=1"/>  in the head part of the parent page

Comment: Thanks all of your comment, i have fix this problem, just change src like this 'http://lifetrainadmin-stg.pa18.com/mladmin-sub/pages/index.html#/quiz-competition/statistic?testId=1308202&trainingClassId=LF20201010100556', then the page can show normal, maybe the src can not as the same of the parent url before '#'

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have fix this problem, just change src like this 'lifetrainadmin-stg.pa18.com/mladmin-sub/pages/index.html#/…', then the page can show normal, maybe the src can not as the same of the parent url before '#'.